# CocoaLibspotify framework

Tags: cocoa, libspotify

I have developed an application using libspotify.framework app is working well but It gives an error at the time of submission on itunes error is "Invalid Signature- the nested app bundle Spotify at path [Macify.app/Contents/Frameworks/libspotify.framework] is not signed" Please see atttched image and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , i have found solution of this problem after more efforts of research .
Solution :
   1) Go to the project navigator in your xcode , click on "Build Phases".
   2) There will be a button "Add Build Phase" click on this .
   3) There will be opened a list then click on "Add Run Script"
   4) Copy below code and paste there :

```
my $infoplist_path = "$ENV{BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/$ENV{FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/libspotify.framework/Resources/Info.plist";

#open the info plist
open(my $input,  "<",  $infoplist_path)  or die "Can't open Info.plist: $!";
my $outputstring = "";

#loop through each line until we find CFBundleExecutable, then substitute the next line
while (+<$input>) {
$outputstring .= "$_";
if (/[\t ]+<key>CFBundleExecutable<\/key>\n/) {
    my $line = +<$input>;
    $line =~ s/([\t ]+<string>)(.*?)(<\/string>)/$1.(libspotify).$3/eg;
    $outputstring .= $line;
 }
 }

 #write back out to Info.plist
 open(my $output,  ">",  $infoplist_path)  or die "Can't open Info.plist: $!";
  print $output $outputstring;
```

5) I am sure if anyone got this problem then it will be solved using this code.